# Multiple FusionTables Queries Not Working

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am using Google Maps API. I want to assign colors to some countries.

To do that, i have to get each country boundaries to be able to draw polygon. So, i'm using FusionTables. For every countries,  I do FusionTables query to get the layer and then set the map. Here what i have done.

```
var countryArray = new Array();
var nodeArray = new Array();
var companyArray = new Array();
var locationsArray = new Array();

function plotMarker() {
var rootMarker = locationsArray[companyArray.indexOf(rootCompany)];
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
var myStyle = [
{
    featureType: "all",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
    { 
        visibility: "off" }
        ]
    }
    ];

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: ['mystyle', google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN]
        },
        center: latlng,
        zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: 'mystyle'
    });

    map.mapTypes.set('mystyle', new google.maps.StyledMapType(myStyle, { name: 'My Style' }));


    for (var i = 0; i < locationsArray.length; i++) {
        if (locationsArray[i] != undefined) {
            var latitude = locationsArray[i].lat() + verDiff;
            var longitude = locationsArray[i].lng() + horDiff; 
            var newLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            var ftoptions = {
                query: {
                  from: '419167',
                  select: 'kml_4326',
                  where: "sovereignt = '"+countryArray[i]+"'"
              },
              suppressInfoWindows:true,
              styles: [
              { 
                polygonOptions: {
                    fillColor:'#0040FF',
                    fillOpacity:0.7
                }
            }
            ]
        };

        var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(ftoptions);
        layer.setMap(map);
    }
}
```

}

But, why does the style only work for the first country? I wonder if the queries are not successfully performed for all countries or just there's something wrong with the style? Any helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A map can only have 1 styled FusionTablesLayer, the styles of the other layers will be ignored.

Create a single FusionTablesLayer and select multiple sovereignt's via a `IN()`-condition

Comment: Thanks, is that able to assign different colors to each country?

Comment: via the layer-setup only for 5 countries(only up to 5 styles will be applied). But you may define [**different colors via a template**](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2681556?hl=en)(based on column-values)